# Удаление проекта на Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Удалила проект на Gitlab через Settings -> Advanced Settings. Но он остался в списке проектов и не даёт сделать повторный Fork проекта, который содержался в удалённом. Как удалить его из списка окончательно?

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте, можно ли открыть "удаленный" проект (url - example.com//<name_project>) и перейти в его настройки? Присутствуют ли какие-то уведомления в верхней части страницы? Например, вот такое:

```
This project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following message: Failed to open TCP connection to <host>:5000
```

Если всё же проект не удалился, то как простое решение можно полностью очистить историю и файлы git - будет новый "чистый" проект.

Comment: Автор вопроса не заходил 3 года, поэтому воздержитесь от уточнений и вопросительных форм в ответе.

Comment: @0xdb согласен, к сожалению, не сразу заметил дату вопроса.